# ngFor not always capturing clicks

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm building an app using Ionic 2, and I've noticed a strange issue with ngFor.  For some reason, I have to tap each item in the list 2x in order for the (click) function to be executed.  What's more, I have to wait a full second in between clicks, or it won't work.  And to complicate it further, it has this weird bug 80% of the time, but works other times as it should.  This only occurs on safari on the iOS device, not in safari on the computer.  Here is the code:

```
  <div class="list">
    <div *ngFor="let item of recordingsList" (click)="goToRecordingDetails(item)" onclick="console.log('clicked',event)">
      {{item.name}}
      <span class="delete-list-item-button" (click)="deleteRecording(item, $event)" [hidden]="!editing">Delete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any idea what could be causing it to act funky?  I did the timeline in safari, and confirmed that safari knows that the event is getting fired, it just won't respond to it. [image]

UPDATE: I found that it's not that I have to click the item twice, it is that I have to wait 3 full seconds before I can click anything in the list.  So the issue is not having to click 2x, the real issue is that clicks don't do anything for the first 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mix `(click)` and `onclick`

Comment: It wasn't working without `onclick` i just added it in the course of debugging.

Comment: Try: `(click)="goToRecordingDetails(item); console.log('clicked',$event)"`